# how to Publish my Facebook app?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I build an app using the same app I mostly used to publish post but it is a test app.

I want to allow some of my clients to publish via this app but it gives error:

> App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode,and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

```
dynamic result = fb.Post("399044920269485/feed", new { message = menulist });
var newPostId = result.id;
```

How should I publish my app so that person accessing app become the registered user?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here app submission process details https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process

Comment: You don’t need to send an app for review just to set it public.

Comment: @CBroe if your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#review

Comment: The app can still be used as long as it is set public – only asking for those permissions requires them to be reviewed. (So, yes, he might have to get permissions reviewed as well – but just setting the app itself public does not require any review.)